# How to duplicate a RuleContext

Tags: antlr4

Is there any way to duplicate a ParserRule? I need a real deep copy, so copyFrom() doesn't do the trick. Or must I re-parse the code?

An alternative idea how to solve the following would also be much appreciated:

I am working on a compiler, translating old legacy code to modern programming languages, in this case EGL -> Java.
EGL has a concept called Standalone Function, which are similar to C-macros. This means that code inside the functions can reference symbols in the calling scope. So both defining and resolving of symbols and type promotion are context-dependent.

In ANTLR3, we solved this by dupTree(), and simply made a copy to work on in each calling scope.

Dynamic types is not an option.

Example (pseudo code) to illustrate:

```
Program A
    int var = 4;
    saf();    # Prints 5 
end A;

Program B
    String var = "abc";
    saf();    # Prints abc1 
end B;

function saf()
    int j = 1;
    print(var + j);
end saf;
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 4.2, ANTLR 4 does not include any API for manipulating the structure of a parse tree after the parse is complete. This is an area we are currently exploring, especially considering the possibilities created by the new pattern matching syntax.

For duplicating trees, I recommend you implement the visitor interface created when you generated your parser. This will allow you to call `visit` on any node in your parse tree to create a deep copy of that node.

Comment: I wish the copy visitor or listener was auto-generated :(

Comment: Is there a github issue we can track for this? Is there a recommended approach in Antlr 4.7 (the latest)?